# Reducing Code by Combining Select Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have about 9 select distinct statements that are 186 lines each. Currently they are combined using a union all and work fine. It returns 30,416 rows and ends up being 1008 lines of code. Is it possible to combine all 9 select statements into 1 select statement and get accurate results? The select statements are identical except for a few columns which vary based on on something like CourseID1 and CourseID2 or Credit1 and Credit2 ect... I combined these case statements doing something like this for most of them a few were more complicated,

```
,case
        when com.pxTITLE1 is not null then com.pxTITLE1 
        when com.pxTITLE2 is not null then com.pxTITLE2
end as CollegeCourseDescrip
```

this was previously written as `,com.pxTITLE1 as com.pxTITLE1`. There are somewhere around 76 columns in this monster. My join statements look like this:

```
FROM PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENT  as com
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode
            on com.pxORIGINAL1 = comcode.pxKEY 
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode2
            on com.pxORIGINAL2 = comcode2.pxKEY
        join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode3
            on com.pxORIGINAL3 = comcode3.pxKEY
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode4
            on com.pxORIGINAL4 = comcode4.pxKEY 
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode5
            on com.pxORIGINAL5 = comcode5.pxKEY 
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode6
            on com.pxORIGINAL6 = comcode6.pxKEY 
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode7
            on com.pxORIGINAL7 = comcode7.pxKEY
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode8
            on com.pxORIGINAL8 = comcode8.pxKEY 
         join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcode9
            on com.pxORIGINAL9 = comcode9.pxKEY 

        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL1,6) = comcodename.pxKEY 
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename2
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL2,6) = comcodename2.pxKEY 
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename3
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL3,6) = comcodename3.pxKEY 
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename4
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL4,6) = comcodename4.pxKEY
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename5
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL5,6) = comcodename5.pxKEY
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename6
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL6,6) = comcodename6.pxKEY
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename7
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL7,6) = comcodename7.pxKEY 
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename8
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL8,6) = comcodename8.pxKEY 
        left join PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_COMMENTCODE  as comcodename9
            on left(com.pxORIGINAL9,6) = comcodename9.pxKEY 

        JOIN CFC_Extract_Blank.dbo.src_CourseList_Imp as crs
            ON comcode.pxEQUIVID = crs.CourseCode
        left JOIN CFC_Extract_Blank.dbo.src_TermList_Imp as trm
            ON trm.TermCode = ltrim(rtrim(com.pxYEARTERMCODE))
        LEFT JOIN PoiseDump.dbo.PX_REGISTRAR_FILES_STUDENT as STUDENT
            ON com.pxSTUDENTID = STUDENT.pxSTUDENTID

where pxORIGINAL1  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal1) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL2  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal2) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL3  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal3) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL4  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal4) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL5  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal5) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL6  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal6) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL7  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal7) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL8  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal8) > 6 and
        pxORIGINAL9  is not null and LEN(pxoriginal9) > 6

GO
```

After rewriting this and combining the select statements the code is working and reduces it down to 301 lines. However, my results have also changed to 403 rows. I'm sure it is in the way I have the joins written. I have tried several different ways but nothing seems to give me anywhere near what the results should be. Am I chasing something that just isn't possible here? Any tips on how to go about doing this? Thanks!!

Comment: Shawna, please investigate the difference between "UNION ALL" and "UNION".

Comment: Good point. However, even changing it to just a union only eliminates about 15 records. Regardless, if possible i'd like to just eliminate all the select statements  for simplicity purposes. It makes it more difficult to go in to modify or locate an error later. When the selects are so similar it just seems unnecessary to repeat so many times.

Comment: Problems like this are symptomatic of (appallingly) poor design. See normalisation, and amend the design accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry I looked that up and that does give me an idea. I may still need to write multiple select statements but I could reduce their size dramatically!

Comment: I agree. It is driving me crazy and it's the way they wrote the code.  I was given the code and told to find the errors and fix them and just repeat the select statement 9 times. They don't seem to be worried about the size at the moment and just want it done quickly due to some deadlines. We seem to be disagreeing about how these should be written.

Comment: Is that a nine-way self-join? I feel dizzy, I need to sit down... IMO combining these already over-complicated statements will just make the code even more difficult to understand. You'd be better off spending the time figuring out a better way organize and query the data.